# ORDER BY giving wrong order

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have an SQL statement in my C# program that looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM XXX.dbo.XXX 
WHERE Source = 'OH'
  AND partnum = '1231202085' 
ORDER BY partnum, Packaging, Quantity
```

When running this query in SQL Server Management, the results are ordered as expected.
My first 3 results have the same partnum and Packaging with Quantities of 32.0, 50.8, and 51.0.

However, when I run the query from my program, the result set with quantity 50.8 is the first to be returned. The datatype of Quantity is decimal(18,9). I've tried cast, it doesn't appear to be a datatype problem.

I cant figure out why its getting the middle quantity.

---

Thank you guys for the quick responses however after a little more testing I found my issue in my C# code, not the sql.

After getting the query results I hade:

`if (PurchOrder.Read())`
      `while (PurchOrder.Read())`

Overlooking the fact that the first read would in fact read my first result, then the while whould get my second result.

Ive replace the if statement with:

`if (PurchOrder.HasRows == true)`

and everything looks to fine.

Again, thank you for the responses though. Sorry for the mislead question.

-Cody

Comment: Please show your C# code.

Comment: Can you show the code snippet where you run the query?

Comment: You've added the SQL Statement, but you haven't provided the C# / client code that uses this statement.  Please add the relevant C# code so we can help you.

Comment: @Cody you can remove the `HasRows` check entirely.  If there are no rows, the first `Read` call will return false, and all will be well.

Comment: @Cody you might want to put that in as "Your own answer" and accept it tomorrow.  That way this question doesn't look like an open ended question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the quick responses however after a little more testing I found my issue in my C# code, not the sql.

After getting the query results I hade:

if (PurchOrder.Read())
while (PurchOrder.Read())

Overlooking the fact that the first read would in fact read my first result, then the while whould get my second result.

Ive replace the if statement with:

if (PurchOrder.HasRows == true)

and everything looks to fine.

Again, thank you for the responses though. Sorry for the mislead question.

-Cody

Answer (score 1):

If partnum is alphanumeric, it's not going to sort in numerical order unless you either

- Left Pad partnum out to the exact same number of characters
- Sort with some specialized alphanumeric sorting. I typically use:

  ```
  order by
  RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 1000) + LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST([field_name] AS VARCHAR(8000)))), 1000)
  ```

Of course, you can use much lower padding numbers, if your fields are smaller.

Comment: But the OP states that the three Quantity values belong to records with the same partnum value; those records would be adjacent regardless of whether partnum is sorted numerically or alphanumerically.

Comment: But he actually said `in SQL Server Management, the results are ordered as expected` so it can't be a data type issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the SQL Server side as long as partnum, packaging, and quantity are a numeric/float field this should work absolutely fine.  What worries me is if packaging or partnum is a text type variable where `10` comes before `2`.

To avoid this you must `CONVERT` or `CAST` the data type to an integer / decimal type before performing the `ORDER BY`.  Look up CAST / Convert in [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

For instance this:

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
 mytest varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #test(mytest) VALUES('10')
INSERT INTO #test(mytest) VALUES('1')
INSERT INTO #test(mytest) VALUES('2')
INSERT INTO #test(mytest) VALUES('12')
INSERT INTO #test(mytest) VALUES('20')

SELECT * FROM #test ORDER BY mytest
DROP TABLE #test
```

Produces incorrect ordering.  And could be handled like so:

`SELECT * FROM #test ORDER BY CAST(mytest AS INT)`

As far as from the client side (C#) are you storing this in some sort of gridview?

Comment: But he actually said `in SQL Server Management, the results are ordered as expected` so it can't be a data type issue.

Comment: @MostyMostacho - Could be...but he also posted the same query after asking for it.